# How to use documentation of azure DevOps python API, I am trying to get what members an object has when API call is made?

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops

I'm using the python API for Azure DevOps, I am trying to get a list of repo and branches each repo has. I don't know what members an object has when the API call returns the object. I am not sure if the [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) is complete, How to know what members an object has?

like for an object of "repo", I guessed the "name" property

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
import pprint

# Fill in with your personal access token and org URL
personal_access_token = 'YOURPAT'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/YOURORG'
project_name = "XYZ"

# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

# Get a client (the "core" client provides access to projects, teams, etc)
git_client = connection.clients.get_git_client

# Get the first page of projects
get_repos_response = git_client.get_repositories(project_name)

index = 0
for repo in get_repos_response:
  pprint.pprint(str(index) + "." + repo.name)
  index += 1
```

In the above code, I just guessed the name property of a repo. I want to know what branches each of these repos have.

TIA

Comment: I am looking for more meta regarding branches like, when the branch was last used, who created the branch..

Comment: Just want to confirm how’s the things going now? Does below sample could give you the help on your puzzle solved? If not, free to comment below:-)

Comment: Thanks, @Merlin Liang, I am using the functions directly for a list of repos, branches. But I still am not sure about the branch creator, last modified time or such things.

Comment: Compared with the Boto3 documentation, that for the Azure Devops is pretty hopeless ! No listing of properties, methods, attributes; how to "get" various elements and objects ...

Answer (score 1):

Based on these description, you want to apply the python api to get **Repos list**, **branch list of corresponding repos** and **the creator of branch**. For *>>when the branch was last used*, not sure whether it means the latest update time of the branch.

If this, just refer to this [source code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/dev/azure-devops/azure/devops/v6_0/git/git_client_base.py).

- **[Get repositories](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/dev/azure-devops/azure/devops/v6_0/git/git_client_base.py#L2987)**:

  It can only be got based on the project name provided, so use [`_send`](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/3838e91d662dba1f77b43ad560ca23c1cb7e84e8/azure-devops/azure/devops/client.py#L71) to pass the parameters to client:

  ```
  route_values = {}
  if project is not None:
      route_values['project'] = self._serialize.url('project', project, 'str')
  query_parameters = {}
  if include_links is not None:
      query_parameters['includeLinks'] = self._serialize.query('include_links', include_links, 'bool')
  if include_all_urls is not None:
      query_parameters['includeAllUrls'] = self._serialize.query('include_all_urls', include_all_urls, 'bool')
  if include_hidden is not None:
      query_parameters['includeHidden'] = self._serialize.query('include_hidden', include_hidden, 'bool')
  response = self._send(http_method='GET',
                        location_id='225f7195-f9c7-4d14-ab28-a83f7ff77e1f',
                        version='6.0-preview.1',
                        route_values=route_values,
                        query_parameters=query_parameters)
  return self._deserialize('[GitRepository]', self._unwrap_collection(response))
  ```
- [Get branches](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/dev/azure-devops/azure/devops/v6_0/git/git_client_base.py#L238):

  Add `repository_id` and `base_version_descriptor` additionally:

  ```
  if project is not None:
      route_values['project'] = self._serialize.url('project', project, 'str')
  query_parameters = {}
  if include_links is not None:
      query_parameters['includeLinks'] = self._serialize.query('include_links', include_links, 'bool')
  if include_all_urls is not None:
      query_parameters['includeAllUrls'] = self._serialize.query('include_all_urls', include_all_urls, 'bool')
  if include_hidden is not None:
      query_parameters['includeHidden'] = self._serialize.query('include_hidden', include_hidden, 'bool')
  ```
- `branch creator` and `the latest update time`, these message are contained in one specified branch and should be get by [getting branch](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/dev/azure-devops/azure/devops/v6_0/git/git_client_base.py#L207). At this time, the `name` is necessary which represent one specified **branch name**:

  ```
  route_values = {}
  if project is not None:
      route_values['project'] = self._serialize.url('project', project, 'str')
  if repository_id is not None:
      route_values['repositoryId'] = self._serialize.url('repository_id', repository_id, 'str')
  query_parameters = {}
  if name is not None:
      query_parameters['name'] = self._serialize.query('name', name, 'str')
  if base_version_descriptor is not None:
      if base_version_descriptor.version_type is not None:
          query_parameters['baseVersionDescriptor.versionType'] = base_version_descriptor.version_type
      if base_version_descriptor.version is not None:
          query_parameters['baseVersionDescriptor.version'] = base_version_descriptor.version
      if base_version_descriptor.version_options is not None:
          query_parameters['baseVersionDescriptor.versionOptions'] = base_version_descriptor.version_options
  ```

Comment: How do you determine what values go into the `route_values` dict? I can't seem to find any sort of documentation on what goes into those. Otherwise, how do you know what can go in there?

Comment: Should one rely on private "underscore" methods ? That detail should really be wrapped by the Python API.